# Is there a version for Google Earth Pro x64 in Windows?

Tags: google-earth, 64bit

As the title says. I have looked more or less everywhere and couldn't find any definitive answer. If not for Windows, is there a x64 version for *nix (Ubuntu, Debian etc)?

Otherwise, with 32-bits Google Earth and 3 GB memory limit, is a SSD the best and only option to speed up things a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no 64bit version for Windows** as Google Earth Pro (default) installs into C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Earth Pro even on a 64 Operating System

Side Note
There are options for Linux 64bit Operating Systems but the software this is just for the operating system structure not the application (still 32bit)

The give away when install is installed
Program Files (x86) is for 32 bit applications

[image]

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/07HHrAG0qi8

Comment: I guessed as much, but wanted to make sure. It's would really be a good thing to have a pure x64 version.

Answer (score 1):

The 64-bit Google Chrome also installs to C:/Program Files (x86), but runs a full 64-bit version.

So, for Google products at least, this is not a reliable way of determining 32-/64-bit versions.

Comment: If you look at Task Manager - if the process name says *32 beside it (when you're on a 64bit machine), its a 32bit process. Else its 64bit. If you're on a 32bit machine, the process is just 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  Full 64-bit version of Google Earth Pro, version 7.3.1, is available as of 1/22/2018.

See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/Lk39vUdm0Kk.

A Googler in the Earth Outreach team says, "the update should roll out to all users within the next few weeks," but you can direct download from https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html

Answer (score 0):

Full 64-bit version of Google Earth Pro, version 7.3.1.4505 download link:

https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/advanced/current/googleearthprowin-7.3.1-x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Here is the latest version as of 9/10/2018

https://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/advanced/current/googleearthprowin-7.3.2-x64.exe